# std::pair and copy-assigning it in a map implementation

Tags: c++, iterator

Let me start by giving you a basic associative-array implementation.

```
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

namespace chops {
template <typename Key, typename Value,
          typename Compare = std::less<Key>>
struct map {
    using value_type = std::pair<const Key, Value>;
    using key_type = Key;
    using mapped_type = Value;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using key_compare = Compare;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using const_reference = value_type const&;
    using iterator = typename std::vector<value_type>::iterator;
    using const_iterator = typename std::vector<value_type>::const_iterator;

    iterator begin() {
        return data.begin();
    }

    iterator end() {
        return data.end();
    }

const_iterator begin() const {
    return data.begin();
}

const_iterator end() const {
    return data.end();
}

const_iterator cbegin() const {
    return data.cbegin();
}

const_iterator cend() const {
    return data.cend();
}

    size_type size() {
        return data.size();
    }

    bool empty() {
        return data.empty();
    }

    void clear() {
        data.clear();
    }

    mapped_type& operator[](Key const& k) {
        key_comp kc{k};
        iterator it = std::find_if(begin(), end(), kc);
        if(it == end()) {
            auto n = std::make_pair(k, mapped_type{});
            data.push_back(n);
            return data.back().second;
        } else
            return (*it).second;
    }

    template< class... Args >
    std::pair<iterator,bool> emplace(Args&&... args) {
        value_type v{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
        key_comp kc{v.first};
        iterator it = std::find_if(begin(), end(), kc);
        if(it == end()) {
            data.push_back(v);
            return std::make_pair(data.end()--, true);
        } else
            return std::make_pair(it, false);
    }

    void erase(iterator pos){
        data.erase(pos);
    }

private:
    struct key_comp {
        Key k;
        bool operator()(value_type const& p1) {
            return p1.first == k;
        }
    };
    std::vector<value_type> data;
};
}

int main() {
    chops::map<int, std::string> m1;
    m1[1] = "Burak";
    m1.emplace(2, "Kaan");
    m1.emplace(3, "Copur");

    for (auto& kv : m1) 
        std::cout << kv.first << " has value " << kv.second << std::endl;
    m1.erase(m1.begin());    
    for (auto& kv : m1) 
        std::cout << kv.first << " has value " << kv.second << std::endl;
}
```

First, the code uses vector to store key-value pairs. This makes implementation easy but operations are not O(log(n)) like balanced-tree implementations or O(1) like hashing-based implementations. In fact, this is a container of containers in a sense and the outer container may be parametrized in an implementation. Anyways, my problem is about that erase function, which I just delegate to erase function of underlying vector. Compiler tells me that copy constructor is removed from the pair type, since it has a user-defined move. Erase tries to copy the parts after the erase place I guess, and tries to use copy-constructor there.

The thing is, I devised a minimal example as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main() {
    auto p1 = std::make_pair(1, "Burak");
    auto p2 = std::make_pair(2, "Kaan");

    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> v1;
    v1.push_back(p1);
    v1.push_back(p2);

    v1.erase(v1.begin());
}
```

where I can easily erase from vectors. So, what might be not working in my `erase` implementation?

Comment: change your 'working' example to `std::vector<std::pair<const int, std::string>> v1;` and solve that

Comment: @MikeVine So when a part of pair is const, it is like whole pair is const since you can't change or assign to it?

Comment: `pair<x, y>` effectively is a `struct` with members `x` and `y`. If either of those are `const` then the rules apply for any class with const members - default copy and move constructors are not provided for you as they wouldn't be able to do anything sane. So yes - you can store the underlying items as non-const and only let the users access them with a cast to a `std::pair<const A, B>`

Comment: There's nothing particularly insurmountable about actually using `std::pair<const key_t, value_t>`, and I'm pretty sure that most C++ library implementation do just that. Just because this effectively deletes the default copy/move constructors does not mean that the usual map operations cannot be implemented. There's nothing about the usual map operations that requires copyability or movability of the map's contents.